# Adding a textfield widget to Stack results in RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create the following design
[image]

Nothing complex. I'd be done in 30 minutes if it was just plain HTML and CSS but its not and Flutter is driving me nuts. Below is the code

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {   
        return 
         Stack(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: 
              [
                Expanded(
                child:  TextField(
                  maxLength: 140,
                  decoration:  InputDecoration(
                    filled: true,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 5, right: 60, bottom: 5),
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey[800]
                    ),
                    hintText: "Write something here",
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    focusedBorder:  OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 25.0),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 25.0),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
            )],
          ),
           
            Positioned(
              right: 0,
              top: 0,
              child: Center(
                child:   
                  _selectedIcon == null ?  ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all<double>(0), 
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.transparent)
                    ),          
                    onPressed: () async {
                      final IconData? result = await customiconpickerFuture( context: context, defalutIcon: _selectedIcon);
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedIcon = result;
                      });
                    },
                      child: _selectedIcon == null ? const Icon(
                        IconData(0xe907, fontFamily: 'icomoon'), 
                        color: Colors.black, 
                        size: 40,
                        ) : Icon(_selectedIcon,size: 70, color: Colors.black, ) 
                  )
                  : ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all<double>(0), 
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.transparent)
                    ),          
                    onPressed: () async {
                      final IconData? result = await customiconpickerFuture( context: context, defalutIcon: _selectedIcon);
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedIcon = result;
                      });
                    },
                      child: Icon(_selectedIcon,size: 40, color: Colors.black, ) 
                  )
                 
                  // this button is used to show the icon picker
                 
              
              ),
            ) 
          ],
        );
            
    }
```

I have an idea what the problem is. There are no constraints being passed to the Expand widget therefore its colliding with the Row widget. I've tried various other ways but none is working. Any ideas?

Comment: why do you need a Row and an Expanded widget? TextField will take the entire width of the screen.

Comment: @AmateurCoder When I try that I end up with:

"An InputDecorator, which is typically created by a TextField, cannot have an unbounded width.\nThis
happens when the parent widget does not provide a finite width constraint. For example, if the
InputDecorator is contained by a Row, then its width must be constrained. An Expanded widget or a
SizedBox can be used to constrain the width of the InputDecorator or the TextField that contains
it."

Comment: Then try Row with Flexible instead of Expanded

Answer (score 1):

I have try other way using [**`suffixIcon`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/suffixIcon.html), you should try this.just change my Icon with your icon, hope it help to you.

```
 TextField(
      maxLength: 140,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        //Using IconButton
        suffixIcon: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print('Button Pressed');
          },
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.add,
          ),
        ),
        //Using InkWell
        /* suffixIcon: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            print('Button Pressed using inkwell');
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ), */
        filled: true,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 20,
          top: 5,
          right: 60,
          bottom: 5,
        ),
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey[800],
        ),
        hintText: "Write something here",
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            width: 25.0,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(30),
          ),
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            width: 25.0,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(30),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot. Can't understand how somethins so simple can be so complicated

Comment: If your problem is solved then accept and upvote this answer

Comment: Doesn't work. Returns the error, 'An InputDecorator, which is typically created by a TextField, cannot have an unbounded width'

Comment: are you try my solution?

Comment: Yes. Doesn't work as mentioned above

Comment: Its working correctly test on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true)

Comment: Doesn't work on my side

Comment: ok, i figured out what was wrong. Your answer works

Comment: If its helpful accept and upvote it